# Magento: Fishpig/Wordpress extension not parsing local.xml on Post pages

Tags: wordpress, templates, magento, layout, local

So I setup Fishpigs Wordpress extension about a month ago on my Magento site and all was working well. Somewhere, somehow in the last week the formatting went haywire. Tracking down what went wrong, I found that the post pages stopped using my custom .phtml layout ('wordpress.phtml'). All other wordpress related pages use the template properly though.

I had added

```
<wordpress_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/wordpress.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</wordpress_default>
```

in my **local.xml** and all was good. Today I even tried setting all the layouts in the extension settings and same deal, only the post page isn't rendering the correct layout. This is a strange problem, I'm not sure where to start looking...

Comment: The easy answer is.. something changed. My first guess would be that your layout or template file was deleted, and the install is using the base layout/template, which doesn't have your code in it of course. Do you have a repository? Can you do a diff? That would be your best bet.

Comment: Oh yes something changed, I agree :) Even if the layout was deleted somehow why would it load all the other pages the way they I set them up to load? I've checked and all the correct files are there. Unfortunately I set up svn after all this so it's not version controlled currently.

Comment: If you set up your Magento theme correctly, deleting your layout or theme files will cause Magento to look for them in the base theme. If you turn template/path hints on this will give you an idea if this is happening or not.

Comment: Yeah I had already tried that a few hours ago , it is definitely pulling the base template. Other pages are calling it right though which is strange because the reference in my xml is a catch-all for all wordpress pages.

Comment: @JaredEitnier It's a catch all, but local.xml only wins on a per handle basis.  If there's a handle that run later somewhere else, it could be overriding what you're trying to so (see below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three possibilities here (assuming you've already performed the holy rite of clearing your cache storage)

1. The request for the post page isn't loading your `local.xml` file, possibly because its using a different theme and/or design package
2. The post page isn't issuing the `wordpress_default` handle, so although your `local.xml` file is being included, your `setTemplate` action is never called
3. There is a layout update that's called **after** your layout update (either via XML or directly in PHP code) which sets the root template to something else.

Investigate each of these three items and you should find your answer.

Regarding choice #3, I don't have an installation with the FishPig extension installed and haven't used it extensively, but it looks like the extension does some jiggery pokery in `ViewController.php` to automatically set the template to `page/1column.phtml` if the wordpress page object (? I don't know what this is) has a field set to `'onecolumn'` or `'1column'`.

```
parent::loadLayout($handles, $generateBlocks, $generateXml);    

if ($this->_getPage()) {
    $keys = array('onecolumn', '1column');
    $template = $this->_getPage()->getCustomField('_wp_page_template');

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if (strpos($template, $key) !== false) {
            if ($rootBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')) {
                $rootBlock->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd start looking there.

Comment: Well I can toss the 3rd out possibility because this ViewController is only for page calls, not posts. Posts is giving me the issues. Gonna keep digging in.

Comment: #3's still probably it, I'd just notice that ViewController.php was one possible place where this might be happening.

Comment: Is there a way to view which xml files are loading and in what order?

Comment: the ViewController for posts isn't communicating with the admin settings so something very odd is going on for sure.

Comment: Still can't figure out what on so for now I wrote a nasty find/replace hack in jQuery to replace the wrong class-name with the correct class-name in my template.